# Question on analytic continuation of the principal branch of logarithms on $B(1, 1) $

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, analytic-continuation

(Excercise $6$ ,Conway ,page $217$ )

Let $D_0=B(1, 1) $ and $f_0$ be the restriction to $D_0$ of the principal branch of logarithm. For $n\in \Bbb{Z}$ let $\gamma(t) =e^{2\pi i nt}$ for $0\le t\le 1$ . Find a  continuation $\{(f_t,D_t):t\in[0,1]\}$ along $\gamma$ of $(f_0, D_0) $ and show that $[f_1]_1=[f_0+2\pi i n]_1$.

My attempt : (This proof is motivated by the proof of analytic continuation of principal branch of $\sqrt{z}$ [given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56503/977780) )

$D_0=B(1, 1) =B(\gamma(0), 1) $

Define $D_t:=B(\gamma(t), 1) =B(e^{2\pi in t},1)$

$f_t(\gamma(t)) $ can take value $i (2\pi n t+2 k\pi) $ for $k\in \Bbb{Z}$.

Since $f_0(\gamma(0) =0$ , we take $f(\gamma(t)) =2\pi i n t$ otherwise we loose continuity of $f_0$ at the center of $D_0$.

$z\in D_t$ implies $z \space e^{-2\pi in t}\in D_0$.

$\begin{align} f_t(z) :&=f_t(e^{2\pi i nt}) +f_0(ze^{-2 \pi i n t}) \\&= 2\pi i nt +f_0(ze^{-2 \pi i nt})\end{align} $

Hence $\gamma(t) \in D_t $ and $f_t\in \mathscr{H}{(D_t) }$.

To show

1. $e^{f_t(z) }=z $.

Since $e^{f_0(z) }=z$  and $z\in D_t$ implies $ze^{-2\pi i nt}\in D_0$, $$e^{f_0(ze^{-2\pi i nt})}=ze^{-2\pi i nt}$$

$$e^{-2\pi i nt}+{f_0(ze^{-2\pi i nt})}=z$$

$$e^{f_t(z) }=z $$

2. $f_t=f_t'$ on $D_t\cap D_t'$

$z\in D_t\cap D_t'$ implies $w:=ze^{-2\pi i nt}\in D_0$ and $w':=ze^{-2\pi i nt'}=e^{-2\pi i n(t'-t) } w\in D_0$

Hence $\begin{align}f_0(w) &=f_0(e^{-2\pi i n(t'-t) }+f_0(w')\\&=2 \pi i n (t'-t) +f_0(w') \end{align}$

Now $\begin{align}f_t(z) &=f_t(e^{-2\pi i nt} w) \\&=2\pi i nt+f_0(w) \\&=2 \pi i n t +2 \pi i n t(t'-t) +f_0(w') \\&= 2\pi i n t'+f_0(w') \\&=f_{t'}(z) 
 \end{align}$

Hence $f_t=f_{t'}$ on $D_t\cap D_{t'}$.

Hence $\{(f_t,D_t):t\in [0,1]\}$ is an analytic continuation of $(f_0, D_0) $ along the path $\gamma$  where $D_t=B(e^{2\pi i nt}, 1) $ and $f_t(z) =2 \pi i nt +f_0(ze^{-2\pi i nt}) $

Now $f_1(z) = 2 \pi i n +f_0(z) $ $\space  \forall z\in D_0$.

Hence $[f_1]_1=[f_0+2 \pi i n ]_1$

Is the above attempt correct?